# When backward compatibility is bad

Tags: phrase-requests, programming, idiom-requests

Sometimes, making a poor design choice in the past prohibits the programmers from providing neat solutions in the future. You want to abandon the wrong route and start from scratch. Which word or phrase should you choose to stigmatize that bad choice and your situation?

I did not expect it to be a technical term. Might be just a proverb. You might explain to people that something is bad by recalling a proverb.

Comment: You want to know what the equivalent for backwards compatibility is for English? Can you give an example sentence where you will use the word or phrase?

Comment: @MattЭллен, I think (s)he’s asking what you call the situation where backward compatibility is a _hindrance_ that prevents the programmer from doing something desirable in a newer version. I know of no specific term for this.

Comment: what is backward-compatibility? support for legacy software?

Comment: @rps, Yes. I am talking in the sense of legacy that has clung to your leg and does not let you to move forward.

Comment: Excel 2010 is **still** backwards compatible with the original **VisiCalc** 1900-leap-year-not bug.

Comment: "Painting yourself into a corner" is one idiom often used to describe this sort of thing.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there is a specific term but maybe one of these sentences could help:

- the new solution would introduce [*breaking changes*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breaking_change)
- you are *constrained/limited/bound* by the existing solution/framework/...
- you have to provide [*legacy support*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system#Legacy_support)
- your current design violates the [*open/closed principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a metaphor would work:

*The anchor steadies the ship in the storm, but the ship is moored until it weighs anchor.*

Backward compatibility can become a tether that keeps the software from moving forward.

Answer (score 2):

Software engineers use the term [*bug-for-bug compatibility*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_compatibility) to describe the undesirable situation where you need to maintain compatibility even for a product's bugs and misfeatures. (While this is sometimes a boon for end users, it's a hassle for the developers.)

Comment: Thanks. I've seen the term `bugward compatible` in Wiki. The problem with that is that this virtue and fun. I would like to highlight the opposite aspect of this issue, to deter people from it.

Answer (score 0):

The foundation won't support further development  -- or at least it won't support the development that you intend.  You're talking about a system that has a weak foundation.  You want to replace the foundation so you can support a more useful set of extensions.

When you need to extend the metaphor for those non-programming manager types, tell 'em that it's fine to build a bungalow on the beach, but you need bedrock if ya wanna build a skyscraper.

Answer (score -1):

It's sometimes better to start "with a clean slate" - *tabula rasa*.